# Parsing an XML from an e-mail attachment

Tags: iphone, xml, email-attachments

Is there a way to parse an XML which is attached to an e-mail directly from my app? I have implemented a parser which is reading it from the documents path, but would like to allow the user to be able to directly get it from an e-mail attachment too.

Comment: Do you mean you want to open a XML document attachment in mail, which your application pre-processes (like an XML handler?), or be able to click on the attachment and say 'Open with'. The first isn't possible in a non jailbroken iPhone, the second should be. Or do you mean you want your app to read messages from mail?

Comment: The use case is: The recipient receives an email with an attached XML-file. The user of my app then somehow selects that XMl-file and the app parses its content with the same parser I use parsing XML-files from the document path.

Comment: a bit surprised to see the down vote on my question. Guess it is clear, that I would not put a bounty for it, if I would not have investigated myself on the issue.

Comment: Never understood why people downvote a question without asking any questions (unless the question is really stupid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to restrict it to jailbroken files, the easiest way is to register a filetype ([Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1)) with the extension of your data format, so XML if it is a generic XML or some other type if you want to make it specific to your application (and remember if you register XML you will get all XMLs, not just yours), then the user can click on the extension and get the 'Open in....' menu with your application shown in the list.
You need to impliment application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, but it is all in the docs.

A better option would be to give it a filetype that is not commonly used by anything else, so that yours is the only one in the list. I get 4 apps on my iPad for opening XML

There is no way to automatically do it.

Comment: OK, guess I got the concept of your idea. In my case the user would receive the email with the attachment called, let's say abc.abilix (which actually is my XML file). As soon as the user touches that file, to open it, the mentioned dialog with the 'Open in...' would appear and the user would select my app, which in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions could then do the parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Woody, however it seems to me, that this is actually even more complicated for the user, as my current solution, where he has to temporary store the attachment on the filesystem on his workstation and copy it to my app via iTunes. What I really look for is to directly access the attachment of the email from within my app, but is seems that is not possible for security reasons. And btw: Yes I am talking about normal files, not jailbrake stuff.

Comment: Yes, it is the security that is an issue, you have no permission to grab the data files from another app.